# Can someone please explain me the climax of Silicon valley 1

Tags: plot-explanation, silicon-valley

I had watched the silicon valley season 1 but i did not understood the climax. I don't know what is Weissman score, is it good to be more or less. I had went through the technical same question asked but still i am confused. I want to know in detail.

Comment: http://silicon-valley.wikia.com/wiki/Weissman_score

Answer (score 1):

The higher the Weissman score, the more compressed a file is. So a low Weissman score is bad, and a high Weissman score is good.  In *Silicon Valley*, at the end of season 1, Pied Piper achieves a higher Weissman score than anyone ever had.

It is important to note that "Weissman score" was made up for *Silicon Valley*. It is not a real thing.

Comment: I know that It is fake but why have -3 for this question

Comment: I did not down-vote.

Comment: If I recall correctly, they didn't just break the record for highest score, they exceeded the previously assumed maximum theoretically possible score, so they had created a whole new science of compression. Yep, from the wiki: "It was believed that the theoretical limit for a Weissman score was 2.9 but this was disproved when the tech startup company Pied Piper achieved Weissman scores up to 5.2."

Comment: Thanks @ToddWilcox! It's been a while since I saw the season 1 finale. But you're right!